# Send/Stream BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) data with high data rate with Arduino

Tags: bluetooth, ble

My project is to transfer an image wirelessly via BLE from my Sparkfun EDGE board using the Arduino IDE to another laptop. In the following, for simplicity, I have reduced the program to transmit integers via BLE. This already works but it takes a long time (~0.5 seconds) to transfer a few bytes. However, from the BLE specifications, much more should be possible.
This is the stripped down code for the Board using Arduino:

```
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>
#include "utility/HCI.h"    // needed for sendcommand
#include <string>

const char BLE_PERIPHERAL_NAME[] = "Peripheral Hello World BLE";
BLEService Test("83436682-10c6-4dad-acb1-133927f3f080");
BLEStringCharacteristic HelloWorlds("83436682-10c6-4dad-acb1-133927f3f080", BLERead | BLENotify, 512);

#define SERIAL_PORT Serial
#define BAUD_RATE   115200 //(originally, 460800)


void setup() {

  // Start up serial monitor
  SERIAL_PORT.begin(BAUD_RATE);
  
#ifdef BLE_Debug
  BLE.debug(SERIAL_PORT);         // enable display HCI commands
#endif
  BLE.setLocalName(BLE_PERIPHERAL_NAME);
  BLE.begin();
  
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(Test);

  Test.addCharacteristic(HelloWorlds);


  BLE.addService(Test);
  BLE.advertise();
//BLE part end
  }
  


void loop(){
    int period=3000; //minimum time [ms] to be spent in each loop. This is to give the BLE enought time to transmit. To be adjusted depending on the test.
    unsigned long timing=millis();
    
    BLE.poll();
    
    int v1;
    v1 = rand() % 100; 
    
    //Generate 8 integer to be transmitted
    String sixteen=String(v1);
    for (uint32_t ccc=0; ccc < 8; ccc=ccc+1){
     
      v1 = rand() % 100; 
      sixteen = sixteen + " " +String(v1);      
    }
  HelloWorlds.writeValue(sixteen);
  SERIAL_PORT.print(sixteen);
  SERIAL_PORT.print("   ");

  
   while(millis() < timing + period){
   }
    
  }
```

The code compiles, runs on the EDGE board and I receive the random bytes on my phone (NRF app) as well as on the other laptop.
On the other laptop, I use gatttool in the Ubuntu terminal to receive the packets:

```
gatttool -I
connect C0:4B:39:C9:B1:04
char-read-hnd c
```

(I obtain the handle "c" through inspecting the characteristics before).
Then, I do receive the String, but it takes the some hundreds of milliseconds until the integers are displayed. I also automated this in a Python script using *pexpect* and then print the timestamps after the *sendline* and *expect* command and it shows the time difference of ~hundreds of milliseconds.

The data rate that I target should be at least hundreds of bytes per second.

Thank you kind community.

Comment: Why you are using a [deprecated tool](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) for this? Do it with [Bleak](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak) then update the question with the time you record via your script please.